# .htaccess in Subfolder not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url Like

```
http://localhost/coupon/stores.php?store_slug=url
```

I want to change it like this

```
http://localhost/coupon/url
```

I tried with this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /coupon/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule (.*) stores.php?store_slug=$1
```

but its not working
with the above mentioned .htaccess code am getting 500 internal server error.
I am using this .htaccess file in sub folder ie coupon

can anybody check where am doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe it need the [[PT](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)] flag?

Comment: Without any rules on your `.htaccess` does `http://localhost/coupon/stores.php?store_slug=url` work? If it does work, have you checked if mod_rewrite is enabled on apache?

Comment: @Prix yes both query string and apache rewrite are working
i am using wordpress in root folder and url is working fine there that means reqrite mode is working

Comment: @GeorgeMarques  can you please show me how ?

Comment: @user2782183 can you give me an example of how `url` looks like from your above sample `stores.php?store_slug=url` what can url be? A full domain for example like `http://domain.com`?

Comment: @Prix chk this `http://freekishopping.in/coupon/stores.php?store_slug=flipkart`

it want it `http://freekishopping.in/coupon/flipkart`

Comment: @user2782183 Just add it to the end of the RewriteRule line: `RewriteRule (.*) stores.php?store_slug=$1 [PT]`.

Comment: @GeorgeMarques stores page is opening but am not getting value of `stores_slug` with `GET` Menthod and now the `CSS`and `JS` are not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /coupon/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) stores.php?store_slug=$1 [L]
```

There should no spaces between `!` and `-f/d`.

Keep in mind that the above rule is only to make `http://localhost/coupon/url` work, as it will internally redirect any requests from the `coupon` folder to the `stores.php` file.

---

As an additional note, for the CSS, JS, Images, you will need to use absolute path, as using the relative path will assume that the CSS, JS and Images are inside the coupon folder.

So if you had it like this `css/my.css` it will think it is inside `coupon/css/my.css` so you need to use it as `http://yourdomain.com/css/my.css` to avoid that.

And if you place a `/` after the URL it will it will think that's the folder so it would go like this `coupon/flipkart/css/my.css`.

Comment: Thanks Prix its working but how can i get a `/` after flipkart ?

Comment: @user2782183 if you're using the exact above code it should work with and without / at the end of flipkart.

Comment: ya thanks i have to call the CSS and JS with the domain URL Thanks